# flask_sqlalchemy create model from different file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to define and create my models with `flask_sqlalchemy`.

If I do it all in one script, it works:

**all_in_one.py**

```
from config import DevConfig
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = app.config.get("DB_URI")
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Members(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)


def main():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `Members` table is created.

If I split this process into files, I can't seem to get the `db` object to register my `Members` model and do anything.

```
root
│-- config.py
│-- create.py
│-- database.py
│-- members.py
```

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**members.py**

```
from database import db


class Members(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
```

**create.py**

```
from database import db
from config import DevConfig
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = app.config.get("DB_URI")


def main():
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `Members` table does not get created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `import members` below `db.init_app(app)`

```py
from database import db
from config import DevConfig

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(DevConfig)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = app.config.get("DB_URI")


def main():
    db.init_app(app)
    import members

    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is there an alternate way of Flask magically being aware? I had to do this as well